# How to show json data in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, widget, json-view

I have `json` data and I want to show like image below. How to do this ???

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7zMu.png)

I have try some package but not work. Here is data:

```
{deploy: {hash: ac75b1d8664f2494f8aabcc218bb1ca6d819a44c223ddeb1f5367c3f4db51bf0, header: {account: 01f6EE89AC9acA3b01Ee2E33eFdbE899fF89B38D2DC7Fd2baC7B1f62FDD490f3F2, timestamp: 2023-09-22T04:21:30.141Z, ttl: 30m, gas_price: 1, body_hash: be68953c273ff81ac1e62c975d27ecf8eafdda23203d70e116a6684216ebd385, dependencies: [], chain_name: casper-test}, payment: {ModuleBytes: {module_bytes: , args: [[amount, {bytes: 0400e1f505, cl_type: U512}]]}}, session: {Transfer: {args: [[amount, {bytes: 0400f90295, cl_type: U512}], [target, {bytes: 0106ca7c39cd272dbf21a86eeb3b36b7c26e2e9b94af64292419f7862936bca2ca, cl_type: PublicKey}], [id, {bytes: 010100000000000000, cl_type: {Option: U64}}]]}}, approvals: []}}
```

Comment: I'd like to request assistance with properly formatting code and JSON/XML data to make it more understandable for reviewers on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Simply all " " to all the data.

```
    {
    "deploy": {
        "hash": "ac75b1d8664f2494f8aabcc218bb1ca6d819a44c223ddeb1f5367c3f4db51bf0",
        "header": {
            "account": " 01f6EE89AC9acA3b01Ee2E33eFdbE899fF89B38D2DC7Fd2baC7B1f62FDD490f3F2",
            "timestamp": "2023-09-22T04: 21: 30.141Z",
            "ttl": "30m",
            "gas_price": 1,
            "body_hash": "be68953c273ff81ac1e62c975d27ecf8eafdda23203d70e116a6684216ebd385",
            "dependencies": [],
            "chain_name": "casper-test"
        },
        "payment": {
            "ModuleBytes": {
                "module_bytes": "",
                "args": [
                    [
                        "amount",
                        {
                            "bytes": "0400e1f505",
                            "cl_type": "U512"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        "session": {
            "Transfer": {
                "args": [
                    [
                        "amount",
                        {
                            "bytes": "0400f90295",
                            "cl_type": "U512"
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        "target",
                        {
                            "bytes": "0106ca7c39cd272dbf21a86eeb3b36b7c26e2e9b94af64292419f7862936bca2ca",
                            "cl_type": "PublicKey"
                        }
                    ],
                    ["id",
                        {"bytes": "010100000000000000", "cl_type": {"Option": "U64"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }, "approvals": []
    }
}
```